# Best way to bind data in GridView using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I want to know that what is the best way to bind data:

1st way:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="rpt_login" HeaderText="User Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fb_url" HeaderText="URL___" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConString%>"
     SelectCommand="select * from tblemployee">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

2nd way:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="rpt_login" HeaderText="User Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fb_url" HeaderText="URL___" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

C# Code:

```
public void GridViewBind()
{
    string query = makequery();
    sqlconnection con=new sqlconnection("Your Connection string"); 

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

   SqlDataAdapter ad= new SqlDataAdapter(query,con);

   ad.fill(ds);

    if (ds != null)
    {
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = null;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

If i have a way to bind data using Design View so why we use code behind?
Please give me some deep knowledge related to it.
I am using ASP.Net SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I have used the Data Source Controls only  for testing or for quick and dirty projects. I've never used them for important production code. I like it to have compile time safety and debugging capabilities in codebehind. So i advise against controls like `SqlDataSource`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter can you please write the pros and cons using SqlDataSource Control instead Code Behind?

Comment: I couldn't agree more with what @TimSchmelter said. You just have a lot more flexibility to when you require the control to be databound. For example, on insert and update actions. In addition, if for some reason no data is returned, you can easily deal with this scenerio by displaying a custom message.

Comment: @user3441151: pros and cons are subjective and that is [not ontopic anymore on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169230/pros-cons-lists-comparing-two-methods-technologies-etc-constructive-or-not). I have currently also not the time to write a detailed answer.

Comment: I agree with @TimSchmelter. these are not the two ways to `DataBind()`. There are a number of combinations. I am voting to close this as too broad.